# Is it possible to access speed dial key/number associations through the Blackberry SDK?

Tags: blackberry, sdk, keyboard

I have an application in wich I would like to use the key/number associations that one configures in the Blackberry settings. Example, I get those associations and recreate the behaviour, when the user presses 1, the number associated with that key in the speed dial settings is shown in some text box.

Is this possible? Or something else that allows me to transfer the speed dial standard behaviour to my app.